# running angular.js from node.js file

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am new to both Node.js and anguler.js I want to show JSON output to a webpage using angular.js.
My angular.js code is in the node.js file

test.js

```
var pg = require('/data /node_modules/pg');
var serverAddress = localhost';
var serverPort = '1337';
var conString = "tcp://myuser:myuser@localhost/mydb";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
http = require('http');
fs = require('fs');
url = require('url');
path = require("path");
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
console.log("request is--- "+ req.url);;
res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/html"});
getData(res);
}).listen(serverPort, serverAddress);
function getData(res) 
{
client.connect(function(err) 
{
 if(err){
  return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);}
client.query('select * from countrydata;', function(err, result){
  if(err){
    return console.error('error running query', err);}
  res.write("<html ng-app>");
  res.write("<body> Keep it simple....!");
  res.write("<script>");
  res.write("alert('it work!');");
  res.write("</script>");
  res.write("<table ng-controller= countryController>");
  res.write("<td>{{directory}}</td>");
  res.write("</tr>");
  res.write("</table>");
  res.write("<script  
  src=\'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js\'>");
  res.write("</script>");
  for (var i in result)
  {
     var records =result[i];
     if (i=='rows')
     {
       var json = JSON.stringify(result[i]);
     }
    }
    res.write("<script>");
    res.write("angular.controller(countryController, function($scope) {");
    res.write("$scope.directory =" + json);
    res.write("});");
    res.write("</script>");
    res.write("</body>");
    client.end();
    });
```

So when I run this test.js my output on webpage looks like this
output:
Keep it simple....!
{{$directory}}

Html view page source looks list this--

Keep it simple....!{{directory}}https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js>angular.controller(countryController, function($scope) {$scope.directory =[{"country_name":"USA","state":"Alaska"},{"country_name":"USA","state":"Colorado"},{"country_name":"USA","state":"Florida"},{"country_name":"USA","state":"Illinois"},{"country_name":"USA","state":"Louisiana"},{"country_name":"USA","state":"North Carolina"},{"country_name":"CHINA","state":"SHANGHAI"},{"country_name":"CHINA","state":"BEIJING"},{"country_name":"ITALY","state":"FLORENCE"},{"country_name":"ITALY","state":"PISA"},{"country_name":"INDIA","state":"ASSAM"}]});

I am not sure why Controller in not printing the value of $scope. Please let me know how I can correct this.
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't send out HTML content using string concatenation. Try to server your HTML page as a static file. Expose the data as REST service using JSON, then use `$http` service to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things I see:

- You're missing an [`ng-app`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angApp) attribute to actually bootstrap an angular application
- `angular.controller()` isn't part of the API.  I think you're trying to use [`Module.controller()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module#controller) but you must first have a reference to a module that might be created with [`angular.module()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module)
- In the inline `<script/>` block where you're attempting to define the controller you should be using a string literal for the controller name e.g. 'countryController'.  What you have now is a variable which isn't defined... so it'll evaluate to `undefined`.
- Also, you'll need some quotes in the `<table ng-controller="countryController">` tag (they aren't present above).

Soo... you've got some work to do before you'll have this little sample working :-)